# Can't work modal form with method POST in Django

Tags: django

Thats my first project in Django. I want to make table and add items with modal form. I use Mysql database. items which addes manually from phpmyadmin already exist on table but when i try add from modal form it cant added.
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


from .models import Client

def viewpost(request):

    post_list = Client.objects.all()
    context = {
        'posts': post_list
    }
    return render(request, 'mysite/viewtable.html', context)

def add_client(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = Client()
        post.name = request.POST.get('name')
        post.surname = request.POST.get('surname')
        post.address = request.POST.get('address')
        post.gender = request.POST.get('gender')
        post.age = request.POST.get('age')
        post.save()

        return render(request, 'mysite/viewtable.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'mysite/viewtable.html')
```

url.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = {
    path('viewtable/', views.viewpost, name='viewpost'),
    path('viewtable/#add_data_Modal', views.add_client, name='add_client'),
}
```

Comment: please show your template

Comment: Instead of adding all variables to post you can use just `post = Client(request.POST)` and you can use Form or ModelForm.

Comment: <tbody>
              {% if posts %}
                  <tr>
                    {% for post in posts %}
                    <th scope="row">aaa</th>
                    <td>{{post.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{post.surname}}</td>
                    <td>{{post.address}}</td>
                     <td>{{post.gender}}</td>
                      <td>{{post.age}}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>

Comment: @HenryM <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#add_data_Modal"  data-toggle="modal">Add data</a>

Comment: Check `path('viewtable/#add_data_Modal'` is that valid?

Comment: Well thats not a form submit button so won't send it back.  Try showing the whole form rather than just the a link

Answer (score 0):

Before the table and modal form didnt work together. If table worked then modal form didnt add to database or conversely. Now the're work together: Modal form add to database then table show data on page. But when i refresh page data add to databse twice. 
views.py:

```
def viewpost(request):
    post_list = Persona.objects.all()
    context = {
        'posts': post_list
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('name') and request.POST.get('surname') and request.POST.get('address'):
            post = Client()
            post.name = request.POST.get('name')
            post.surname = request.POST.get('surname')
            post.address = request.POST.get('address')
            post.age = request.POST.get('age')
            post.save()



            return render(request, 'mysite/viewtable.html', context)

    else:
        return render(request, 'mysite/viewtable.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats SOLVED. Here's view

```
def viewpost(request):
        post_list = Persona.objects.all()


        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.POST.get('name') and request.POST.get('surname') and 
            request.POST.get('address'):
                post = Persona()
                post.name = request.POST.get('name')
                post.surname = request.POST.get('surname')
                post.address = request.POST.get('address')
                post.age = request.POST.get('age')
                post.save()


                return HttpResponseRedirect('/viewtable')

        else:

            return render(request, 'mysite/viewtabel.html', {'posts': post_list}
```